# Convexity of a set generated by $A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, matrix-rank

Problem:

> Let $X_k = \lbrace A^T A \mid \operatorname{rank} A \ge k, A \textrm{ is an $n \times n$ matrix} \rbrace $. Show that $X_k$ is convex.

I know from the classes that $\operatorname{rank} A^TA = \operatorname{rank} A $. So it suffices to show that for every $A, B \in X_k$ the following relation holds:

$$\lambda A^TA + (1-\lambda) B^TB = C^TC$$, where $\operatorname{rank} C \ge k$. But taking the scalar inside the matrix, we could show that for any $A,B \in X_k$ there exists $C \in X_k$ that:
$$A^TA + B^TB = C^TC$$

I'm stuck here. Can you help me please?

Comment: I would first begin by the case $k=1$, because in this case, $A=U^TV$ with $U,V \in \mathbb{R^n}$, then $A^TA=a V^TU$ and det($\lambda aV^TU+(1-\lambda) a'V'^TU'$) is $\neq 0$ (thus rank $(A)=n$) but for at most $n$ values of $\lambda$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $A^TA$ [is positive semi-definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730421/is-aat-a-positive-definite-symmetric-matrix). Now if $P$ and $Q$ are both positive semi-definite, then we have
$$ \operatorname{rank}(P+Q)\geq \min\{ \operatorname{rank}(P), \operatorname{rank}(Q)\}.$$
A proof of this fact can be found in the following Math.SE question: [Rank of the sum of two positive semi-definite matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100212/rank-of-the-sum-of-two-positive-semi-definite-matrices).

Comment: What does it mean positive semi-definite?

Comment: [Have a look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Positive-semidefinite)

Comment: And isn't it true that for positive semi-definite $P,Q$ we have $$\operatorname{rank}(P+Q)\geq \max\{ \operatorname{rank}P, \operatorname{rank}Q\}.$$

Comment: @InvolutiveAutomorphism Yes, it is true. Anyway if it is true for the $\max$ then it is true for the $\min$ and $\min$ is enough for your purpose. I chose to write $\min$ because it is closer to the title of the question I quoted but of course, you can directly work with the $\max$.